# Bakery doesn't pre-sync accounts

Tags: authentication-authorization

I want to use the [Bakery](https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery) module to login and synchronize users, but I am not able to synchronize existing accounts. [Users that exist only on slave cannot login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66424/bakery-users-that-exist-only-on-slave-cannot-login) confirms Bakery doesn't provide pre-sync facility.

May someone help me to synchronize existing user accounts, possibly at database level, for example with `drush rsync` or `sql sync`?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate), it's no syncing but export and import in two steps. But i cannot tell you if existing users will be replaced, skipped or doubled ..

Maybe [account_sync](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_sync) does what you want.

Also have a look here [How to sync users profiles and user tables in 2 drupal sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129289/how-to-sync-users-profiles-and-user-tables-in-2-drupal-sites).

Comment: I want to replicate users with same user id as Master Site, is it possible with "migrate module" or "Account sync" ? ( My Slave DB only have admin, no other users exist)

Comment: uh - if you want the same userid you probably need to do it by a script yourself, or let the users merge themself with [usermerge](https://www.drupal.org/project/usermerge)

Comment: if you only want to sync the slave admin to master, do it by hand !